# MARIADB and routine : error on declaring routine

Tags: sql, mariadb

I use HeidiSQL to make a stored procedure into my MariaDB DB.
Here's my DB.
MariaDB 10.5, centos 7, HeidiSQL 10.3.0.5771. I do not understand the error message.

```
CREATE TABLE HostName ( 
    ID_HostName INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Name TEXT,
    Platform TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_HostName)   
);

CREATE TABLE UserName (
    ID_UserName INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SAMAccountName TEXT,
    FirstName TEXT,
    GivenName TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_UserName)
);

CREATE TABLE EventData ( 
    ID_EventData INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ObjectType TEXT,
    AccessList TEXT,
    ObjectName TEXT,
    MessageFull TEXT,
    ID_UserName INT NOT NULL,
    ID_HostName INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_UserName) REFERENCES UserName(ID_UserName), 
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_HostName) REFERENCES HostName(ID_HostName), 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_EventData)
);

CREATE TABLE Event (
    ID_Event INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Heure TEXT,
    Provider TEXT,
    Code TEXT,
    Action TEXT,
    OutCome TEXT,
    Niveau TEXT,
    ID_EventData INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_EventData) REFERENCES EventData(ID_EventData), 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_Event)
);
```

Here's my stored procedure, i would like to fill database with JDBC (Logstash jdbc output).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `LOGTOMDB`(
    IN `in_Name` TEXT,
    IN `in_Platform` TEXT,
    IN `in_SAMAccountName` TEXT,
    IN `in_ObjectType` TEXT,
    IN `in_AccessList` TEXT,
    IN `in_ObjectName` TEXT,
    IN `in_MessageFull` TEXT,
    IN `in_Heure` TEXT,
    IN `in_Provider` TEXT,
    IN `in_Code` TEXT,
    IN `in_Action` TEXT,
    IN `in_Outcome` TEXT,
    IN `in_Niveau` TEXT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Name FROM HostName WHERE Name = in_Name ) THEN
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO HostName (Name, Platform) VALUES (in_Name, in_Platform);
        END;
    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT SAMAccountName FROM UserName WHERE SAMAccountName = in_SAMAccountName ) THEN
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO UserName (SAMAccountName) VALUES (in_SAMAccountName);
        END;    
    INSERT INTO EventData (ObjectType, AccessList, ObjectName, MessageFull, ID_UserName, ID_HostName) VALUES( in_ObjectType, in_AccessList, in_ObjectName, in_MessageFull, ID_UserName, ID_HostName );
    INSERT INTO Event (Heure, Provider, Code, Action, Outcome, Niveau, ID_EventData) VALUES( in_Heure, in_Provider, in_Code, in_Action, in_Outcome, in_Niveau, ID_EventData );      
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When i save my procedure, i get this error
[image]

Can you help me?
Regards.

Comment: And line 32 is?

Comment: line 32 is "END", on heidi, i do not have DELIMITER options. But when i source the file on mysql command line, it is the same. MariaDB [xxx]> source /etc/logstash/WORK/aa.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2 in file: '/etc/xxx/WORK/aa.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to END your IF statements

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `LOGTOMDB`(
    IN `in_Name` TEXT,
    IN `in_Platform` TEXT,
    IN `in_SAMAccountName` TEXT,
    IN `in_ObjectType` TEXT,
    IN `in_AccessList` TEXT,
    IN `in_ObjectName` TEXT,
    IN `in_MessageFull` TEXT,
    IN `in_Heure` TEXT,
    IN `in_Provider` TEXT,
    IN `in_Code` TEXT,
    IN `in_Action` TEXT,
    IN `in_Outcome` TEXT,
    IN `in_Niveau` TEXT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Name FROM HostName WHERE Name = in_Name ) THEN
       INSERT INTO HostName (Name, Platform) VALUES (in_Name, in_Platform);
   END IF;
    
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT SAMAccountName FROM UserName WHERE SAMAccountName = in_SAMAccountName ) THEN
       INSERT INTO UserName (SAMAccountName) VALUES (in_SAMAccountName);
   END IF;  
    
   INSERT INTO EventData (ObjectType, AccessList, ObjectName, MessageFull, ID_UserName, ID_HostName) VALUES( in_ObjectType, in_AccessList, in_ObjectName, in_MessageFull, ID_UserName, ID_HostName );
   INSERT INTO Event (Heure, Provider, Code, Action, Outcome, Niveau, ID_EventData) VALUES( in_Heure, in_Provider, in_Code, in_Action, in_Outcome, in_Niveau, ID_EventData );      

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks, i retried and it work! thank you very much juergen.